# GridSearchCV returns worse accuracy than default

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I was working with the Heart Disease Prediction dataset from Kaggle and came up with something odd that I couldn't find an answer.

With default Logistic Regression with 'liblinear' solver (C = 1) I get an accuracy on the train set of 87.26% and 86.81% on the test set. Pretty good. However, I tried using GridSearchCV tweaking C in case I find better values and I constantly get worse results (an accuracy about 85% on train set and 82.5% on test set).

Is GridSearchCV using some other metric for comparing these values of C? I just don't understand why it returns a worse solution.

I leave the last part of my code here.

**Default Logistic Regression**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    
lr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear', random_state = 2)
lr = lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

model_score(lr, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
```

**GridSearchCV**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# Finding better hyperparameters for the Logistic Regression
lr_params = [ {'C': np.logspace(-1, 0.3, 30)} ]

lr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear', random_state = 2)
lr_cv = GridSearchCV(lr, lr_params, cv = 5, scoring = 'accuracy')
lr_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

lr_best_params = lr_cv.best_params_
lr = LogisticRegression(**lr_best_params)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

model_score(lr, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
```

**EDIT**

Full code in this [link](https://github.com/ignacioaristimuno/ArtificialIntelligence/blob/main/Projects/Heart%20Disease%20Prediction.ipynb) (check section 4-4.1).

Comment: There's a possibility that there is a mistake in your code other than the above. One possibility it that logistic regression is overfitting to the training set when doing GridSearchCV. Note that reported training accuracy in GridSearchCV might be the CV accruacy of the training set. Hence it reports a lower training accuracy.

Comment: Yes, you are right that could be. What surprised me is that within one of the C values in the params for GridSearchCV there is one close to 0.9, that is the one that gave better results manually. Could it be due to the cross-validation being held by folds?

Also, I leave the complete code [here](https://github.com/ignacioaristimuno/ArtificialIntelligence/blob/main/Projects/Heart%20Disease%20Prediction.ipynb)  (check section 4-4.1) in case it helps. Thanks